# Has an exchange ever voted with a users tokens?

Tags: erc-20, exchanges, voting

If a token allows tokenholders to vote on some issue/proposal/action or whatever, it is conceivable that a token-exchange that holds its customers' tokens could covertly, or perhaps openly, vote on their behalf.  It seems unlikely to me that an exchange would ever do this, risking their reputation, and I'm skeptical it could be done covertly.  However, vitalik recently warned about this issue (4 months ago at the time of this question) on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6qm0y2/is_the_ethereum_team_defending_their_ground/dkyk94c/), quoted below:

> [tokens with voting] have the following problems: .... situations like everyone putting their coins on exchanges and exchanges voting on users' behalf, with users not really caring how exchanges vote with their money, are likely to happen.

My main objection is that the exchange's token holding contract would need a special function to call the voting function of any tokens that had a voting function.  Their token holding contract would need a generic function that could execute arbitrary function calls.  Wouldn't this raise a lot of red flags?

Comment: An exchange doesn’t need to use a contract to hold tokens any more than a regular token-holder. At present, a malicious exchange can easily covertly vote on a user’s behalf by creating a fake account to receive a “withdrawal” to vote and then redepositing tokens as needed/desired to cover its tracks.

Comment: I hadn't considered that.  However, doesn't this assume that the withdraw function has a backdoor that lets some authority account withdraw unlimited tokens?  I would assume that customer token balances are each mapped to a depositer address, and only that depositer address can issue the function call to withdraw tokens.

Comment: On an exchange, the depositor does not have control over the tokens or the keys. The exchange acts as the trusted mediator between market makers and takers. This is why an exchange can easily pack up shop and run away with all of the money entrusted to it and the reason you shouldn't entrust large sums of tokens to an exchange for long periods of time. Also, you should be afraid of them getting hacked or otherwise compromised.